# Simple operator proof

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be linear operators on vector space $\nu$. There exist an operator $X$ on $\nu$ for which $AX = B$ holds, only if $\text{img}(B) \subseteq \text{img}(A)$.

I would like to see the proof of this statement.

Comment: The only if is just because $\mbox{im} AX\subseteq \mbox{im} A$ in general. But the if is also true and is more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that such an $X$ exists, and let $y \in \mathrm{img}(B)$ so that $Bx = y$ for some $x$. Then also $A(Xx) = Bx = y$, which says that $y \in \mathrm{img}(A)$.